# Set number of rows and columns in boot up TTY

Tags: boot

When the Pi boots up, I find the initial number of rows and columns it outputs too high - all the characters are a bit small and hard to read, especially things like '0' and 'O', 'l' and '1', etc. Is there a way to reduce the number of columns and rows that the initial tty uses, i.e. make the text bigger.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `/boot/config.txt` you can add

```
framebuffer_width=1280
framebuffer_height=720
```

or try adding

```
hdmi_mode=16
```

You can also use

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup
```

to set the font to VGA 16x32, but that doesn't take effect until partway through the boot process

It may be possible to pass a font to the kernel by adding

```
fbcon=font:<name>
```

to `/boot/cmdline.txt` but I haven't found a value for `<name>` that works yet (VGA8x8 is much worse, VGA8x16 is the default). Maybe the kernel can be rebuilt to include VGA16x32

Comment: What's the default value for hdmi_mode? I haven't got my pi to hand so I can't easily check. I was hoping not to drop the resolution - it's a 1080 display. Would specifying a lower resolution also affect the X display?

Comment: Tried a few things out on the PI last night, and the image quality was greatly improved by switching off the TV's auto-scaling mode. Doh! Still, the font is small, it's 50 lines-ish, which means being closer to TV to read the text. Would still like a bigger font (25 lines?) without decreasing the output resolution. The dpkq-reconfigure doesn't appear to be installed on my PI (wheezy).

Comment: @Skizz dpkg-reconfigure (note: d-pkg as in "package", not q) is a fairly critical piece of Debian and must be on the system. It may be in /usr/sbin which may not be in plain users' path. But you need root for it and sudo should look on sbin dirs.

Comment: @XTL: I was typing dpkg-configure - the 'q' was just a typo here. Trying dpkg-reconfigure now.

Comment: @Skizz, dpkg is a debian thing. If you're not using a debian derived distro, you will have to find out the equivalent command for that distro

Comment: @gnibbler: The dpkg thing is sorted. Was typing configure instead of reconfigure! TTY set up nicely now with bigger font.